# How to implement a hashmap with string as a key and value to it is a function to perform

Tags: java, hashmap

I need a logic to change the below source such that

```
if (getString(attributes, NAME_ATTR).equals("Title"))
{
    object.setTitle(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR));
}
else if (getString(attributes, NAME_ATTR).equals("Id"))
{
    object.setID(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR));
}
else if (getString(attributes, NAME_ATTR).equals("PhoneNumber"))
{
    object.setPhoneNumber(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR));
}
else if (*)//lot of cases like this
{
    object.set*(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR));
}
...
```

This needs to be done using a hashMap.

I want to store "Title", "Id", "PhoneNumber", ..etc. as keys in a hashmap and the values should be doing the functionality "object.setTitle(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR))".

```
Keys        |   Values
----------------------------
Title       | object.setTitle(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR)) (should set the tilte field in the object)
            |
Id          | object.setId(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR)) (should set the id field in the object)
            |
etc..       | should set the specific field in the object
```

How can I implement this?

Comment: Couldn't you store the values as `Runnable`? Grab the value using the key, then call `run()`

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can set those values and then add the object to the HashMap.
Also give more information on purpose of doing this. There might be other better ways.

Comment: I am actually writing an XML parser which needs to run in an embedded device. The parser is ready but I have lot of if-else if-else if.. cases and it takes around 8 minutes to parse a 30 Mb xml file with 8000 objects data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Runnable`, or a `Callable`, or any other interface or abstract class as the value type:

```
map.put("Title", new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        object.setTitle(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR))
    }
});
```

And to use it:

```
Runnable r = map.get("Title");
r.run();
```

With Java 8 lambdas, the code is much less verbose:

```
map.put("Title", () -> object.setTitle(getString(attributes, VALUE_ATTR)));
```

Comment: @Sen So use an anonymous class instead of a lamdba (as shown in the first example)

Comment: The sad thing is , I was thinking this will give me better performance than the if-else if-else if.. counterpart. But it doesn't seem so. Is this a correct observation.

Comment: That doesn't surprise me. If your goal is to improve performance, you should first *measure* where time is spent, and optimize the hot spots.

Answer (score 0):

In java 1.5+ this can be solved with enums (take a look at TimeUnit). But you are talking about 1.4. So, you can introduce Attribute interface instead of name & function and manipulate with them:

```
interface Attribute {
    void apply(Object obj);
}
abstract class AttributeAdapter<T> implements Attribute {
    protected final T value;
    protected AttributeAdapter(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    ... // Overrides equals/hashCode/toString
    public String toString() {
        return value == null ? 'null' : value.toString();
    }
}
class TitleAttribute extends AttributeAdapter<String> {
    TitleAttribute(String title) {
        super(title);
    }
    void apply(Object obj) {
        obj.setTitle(value);
    }
}

// And speed up your code:
setAttribute(attributes, ATTR, new TitleAttribute("Some title value"));
...
getAttribute(attributes, ATTR).apply(object)
```